# Replace (add) words case sensitive from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I am new to php and especially to regex.
My target is to enrich textes automatically with hints for "keywords" which are listed in arrays.

So far I had come.

```
$pattern = array("/\bexplanations\b/i",
            "/\btarget\b/i", 
            "/\bhints\b/i",
            "/\bhint\b/i",
);

$replacement = array("explanations <i>(Erklärungen)</i>",
            "target <i>Ziel</i>", 
            "hints <i>Hinsweise</i>",
            "hint <i>Hinweis</i>",
);

$string = "Target is to add some explanations (hints) from an array to 
this text. I am thankful for every hint.";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

returns:

```
target <i>Ziel</i> is to add some explanations <i>(Erklärungen)</i> (hints <i>Hinsweise</i>) from an array to this text. I am thankful for every hint <i>Hinweis</i>
```

1) In generally I wonder if there are more elegant solutions (eventually without replacing the original word)? 
On later state the arrays will contain more than 1000 items... and come from mariadb.

2) How can I achive, that the word "Targets" achives a case sensitive treatment? 
(without duplicate the length of my arrays).

Sorry for my English and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Enclose search words with parentheses in regex patterns and use backteferences in replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose search words with parentheses in regex patterns and use backteferences in replacements.

See this [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/OxSCtJ):

```
$pattern = array("/\b(explanations)\b/i", "/\b(target)\b/i", "/\b(hints)\b/i", "/\b(hint)\b/i", ); 
$replacement = array('$1 <i>(Erklärungen)</i>', '$1 <i>Ziel</i>', '$1 <i>Hinsweise</i>', '$1 <i>Hinweis</i>', ); 
$string = "Target is to add some explanations (hints) from an array to this text. I am thankful for every hint."; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

That way, you will replace with the words found with actual case used in the text.

Note it is very important to make sure the patterns go in the descending order with longer patterns coming before  shorter ones (first `Targets`, then `Target`, etc.)

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This exactly solves my problem and gives me the right direction to further research and studies in this subject area. Although Regex seems to be hart to learn, they are really powerful. Thanks again for your demonstration.

Comment: Finnaly done. Concerning my NewB state here I was not allowed at the time you answered... .

Answer (score 2):

If you project to increase the size of your array and if the text may be a bit long, processing all the text (once per word) isn't a reliable way. Also, with a large array, it isn't reliable to build a giant alternation with all the words.
But if you store all the translations in an associative array and split the text on word-boundaries, you can do it in one pass:

```
// Translation array with all keys lowercase
$trans = [ 'explanations' => 'Erklärungen',
           'target' => 'Ziel',
           'hints' => 'Hinsweise',
           'hint' => 'Hinweis'
];

$parts = preg_split('~\b~', $text);

$partsLength = count($parts);

// All words are in the odd indexes
for ($i=1; $i<$partsLength; $i+=2) {
    $lcWord = strtolower($parts[$i]);

    if (isset($trans[$lcWord]))
        $parts[$i] .= ' <i>(' . $trans[$lcWord] . ')</i>';
}

$result = implode('', $parts);
```

Actually the limitation here is that you can't use a key that contains a word-boundary (if you want to translate a whole expression with several words for instance), but if you want to handle this case, you can use `preg_match_all` in place of `preg_split` and build a pattern that tests these special cases before, something like:

```
preg_match_all('~mushroom pie\b|\w+|\W*~iS', $text, $m);

$parts = &$m[0];
$partsLength = count($parts);

$i = 1 ^ preg_match('~^\w~', $parts[0]);

for (; $i<$partsLength; $i+=2) {

...
```

*(if you have a lot of exceptions (too many) other strategies are possible.)*

Comment: Many thanks. As noob I needed a few hours to go through that line by line. And after testing for learning purposes I am still wondereing about how stable this works especially if I use Input with double whitespace etc. And althought my current skills arent sophisticated enough to get the performance issue completely, my further researches became a significant more specific direction.

Comment: @FriedrichSiever: the performance issue is simple, using `preg_replace` (or `str_replace`) with an array of patterns involves an implicit loop, the subject string is entirely processed for each item of the array (in short if you have 1000 words, the string is parsed 1000 times and this string will grow after each replacement). If you use my solution the string is only parsed one time to build the parts array, then you only have to test for half of the parts (the words) if there's a key in the replacement array (building the replacement array like that, avoids the use of `in_array`)

Comment: @FriedrichSiever: other problem, consider the text: `"a child is playing."` and the array `['child' => 'Kind', 'kind' => 'Art']`, with a `preg_replace` or `str_replace` method, you obtain: `"a child <i>(Kind <i>(Art)</i>)</i> is playing."`. I hope you don't have a text with the word `"fat"`.

Comment: Thank you once again for your kind and precious explanations and examples. They are very instructive for me.